# MS Edge unpacked extension works, but packed = "This extension may have been corrupted."

Tags: microsoft-edge

MS Edge extension works fine when unpacked, but when it's packed, after drag'n drop .crx file into MS Edge extension tab, it installs with no issues, briefly shows it's icon in the toolbar, the extension shows it's "first launched" page too, but a moment later, MSE removes the icon from toolbar, and shows "This extension may have been corrupted." under it's name in extensions tab.

Does anyone know what could cause or how can I track what causing it?

Developer mode and allow extensions from other stores are enabled.

Comment: Have you tried repacking it?

Comment: @jdabtieu Multiple times, even tried use .pem key from previous version - same result.

Comment: Does Edge give you any other information other than "it's corrupted"? Also, are you developing an extension that works on Chromium-based browsers (i.e. both Chrome and Edge) or it is designed to only work on Edge?

Comment: Did you add the `update_url` value to the `manifest.json` file? If not, I suggest you add it and again try to test the issue. Further, try to check that the images you had added in the extension have exact same name and extension, please also check and match the uppercase/ lowercase. If there is any difference then correct it and check again. If you are using an older version of the Edge browser then try to update to the latest version of the Edge browser and again check for the issue.

Comment: @jdabtieu, no, there is no other information, the JS console shows error `Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not fetch data from the Chrome Web Store` when hit `repair` button. This is edge-only extension for myself.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT, yes, `update_url` is set to `https://edge.microsoft.com/extensionwebstorebase/v1/crx`

Comment: Does it show the file name beside the error? or does it take you to the problematic line when you click on the error? In your extension, are you trying to fetch some data? if yes, please try to provide information about it and if possible share the sample code. It may give some clue for the cause of the issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT no, there is absolutely no other information provided...

Comment: @vanowm, as this issue is quite old now, are you facing the same issue with the latest version of Edge or Google Chrome browser? If yes, I would suggest please provide the steps with which we could reproduce the said issue. Let us know if there is anything special in your extension as we are not able to reproduce the issue with our test extensions.